# Density of Lions-Magenes space in fractional Sobolev space on the boundary? (extension by zero)

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonempty bounded open subset (assumed to be sufficiently smooth).

Let $\Gamma$ denote the boundary of $\Omega$, and let $\Gamma_1 \subset \Gamma$ be a (measurable) subset.

For any function $u$ defined a.e. on $\Gamma_1$, let $\tilde{u}$ denote its extension to $\Gamma$ by zero, that is, $\tilde{u} =u$ on $\Gamma_1$ and $\tilde{u} = 0$ on $\Gamma$.

Now I consider the Lions-Magenes space

$$ H^{1/2}_{00} (\Gamma_1) := \{ u \in H^{1/2}(\Gamma_1) \mid \tilde{u} \in H^{1/2}(\Gamma) \}. $$

Is it true that $H^{1/2}_{00} (\Gamma_1)$ is dense in $H^{1/2} (\Gamma_1)$?

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Take $n=2$ and assume that a portion of $\Gamma$ is a segment, say, $[-1,1]\times\{0\}$. Take $\Gamma_1=[-1,0]\times\{0\}$. Then the constant function $u=1$ belongs to $H^{1/2}(\Gamma_1)$ but if you extend it to zero outside $\Gamma_1$ you get a $BV$ function, with a jump. If you compute it directly, you should be able to prove that $\tilde u\notin H^{1/2}([-1,1]\times\{0\})$. This has to do with the embedding in fractional Sobolev spaces. In one dimension I think that $BV((0,1))$ is contained in $W^{s,p}((0,1))$ for $sp<1$ but not for $ps\ge 1$.

**Update**
Tartar's book [Sobolev](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540714828) has a chapter on the Lions-Magenes spaces. In particular he shows that if $u\in H^{1/2}_{00}(\mathbb{R}_+)$ then $\frac{u}{\sqrt  x}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}_+)$ with a continuous bound. If you had density, then for  $u\in H^{1/2}(\mathbb{R}_+)$ you could find a sequence $u_n\in H^{1/2}_{00}(\mathbb{R}_+)$ with $u_n\to u$. By pointwise convergence and Fatou's lemma you would have $\Vert \frac{u}{\sqrt  x}\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}_+)}\le\liminf_n \Vert \frac{u_n}{\sqrt  x}\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}_+)}\le C$. Take a  function $u\in H^{1/2}(\mathbb{R}_+)$ such that $u=1$ in $[0,1]$. Then you have a contradiction.

**Update 2**
Take a look at this paper [paper](http://eotarola.mat.utfsm.cl/Archivos/SP_master.pdf). The space $H^{1/2}_{00}$ is defined as the space of $u\in H^{1/2}$ such that $\frac{u}{d}\in L^2(\Omega)$ and the norm is $$\Vert u\Vert_{H^{1/2}}+\Vert \frac{u}{d}\Vert_{L^{2}}.$$  With this norm it is complete. So it all depends on which norm you take in $H^{1/2}_{00}$.

Comment: Thank you for your interest and your answer. I do agree that, in your example, $\tilde{u} \notin H^{1/2}$. Nevertheless, my question is not to prove that $H^{1/2}_{00}(\Gamma_1) = H^{1/2}(\Gamma_1)$, but to prove that $H^{1/2}_{00}(\Gamma_1)$ is dense in $H^{1/2}(\Gamma_1)$. With your example, my question would be: can we approximate the constant function 1 by a sequence of functions in $H^{1/2}_{00}(\Gamma_1)$? Thank you again.

Comment: I think that the space $H^{1/2}_{00)$ is closed (I don't remember which norm you take in that space though), so exactly because $H^{1/2}_{00)\ne H^{1/2}$ you cannot have density.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since $H^{1/2}_{00} (\Gamma_1) \subset H^{1/2} (\Gamma_1)$, I consider the induced norm ... With this norm, I do not think that $H^{1/2}_{00} (\Gamma_1)$ is closed, is it?

Comment: I think it is closed. Need to go to work but I will think about it.

Comment: OK thank you for your time. I will think about it. Just a remark: in the case where we work on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (and not on $\Gamma_1 \subset \Gamma$), then $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ is dense in $H^{1/2}(\Omega)$. As a consequence, $H^{1/2}_{00}(\Omega)$ is dense in $H^{1/2}(\Omega)$. The question is: is this result true with $\Gamma_1 \subset \Gamma$?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Gio67. I do understand your argument. I gave a look in Tartar book. Indeed, it is proved that if $u \in H^{1/2}_{00}(\mathbb{R}_+)$ then $\frac{u}{\sqrt{x}} \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}_+)$. Nevertheless, I do not find the "continuous bound". Is that true?

Comment: I am a little bit surprised since in the book of Lions-Magenes, it is written that $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$ is dense in $H^{1/2}(\Omega)$ ... As a consequence, I thought that if $\Gamma_1$ is an open subset of $\Gamma$, then $\mathcal{D}(\Gamma_1)$ is dense in $H^{1/2}(\Gamma_1)$. As a consequence, $H^{1/2}_{00}(\Gamma_1)$ is dense in $H^{1/2}(\Gamma_1)$. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: he is using embeddings on interpolation spaces. The embeddings are linear and continuous. That's where you get the control on the norms.

Comment: as for your other question, I don't know. I would have to read that proof.

Comment: Tartar says that $H^{1/2}_{00}(\Omega)=(H^1_0(\Omega),L^(\Omega))_{1/2,2)$. Interpolation spaces are complete. So $H^{1/2}_{00}(\Omega)$ seems to be closed (the norm should be the same, I think....). He also says that $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ is dense in $H^{1/2}(\Omega)$ so yeah, I am definitely missing something....

Comment: I saw your update 2. The article you sent me is very interesting. Thank you. In my problem, the norm considered on $H^{1/2}_{00}(\Gamma_1)$ is just the induced norm of $H^{1/2}(\Gamma_1)$. 

I do not want to consider another norm. For example, we know that $H^1(\Omega)$ is complete (and thus closed) with its usual norm. On the other hand, it is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$ considering the induced norm of $L^2(\Omega)$.

My question is exactly the same, but with $H^{1/2}_{00}(\Gamma_1) \subset H^{1/2}(\Gamma_1)$.